# Where to override shouldStartLoadWithRequest method?

Tags: ios, cordova

I recently updated to cordova 6.0. In my code in the MainViewController I implemented shouldStartLoadWithRequest UIWebViewDelegate method to do some basic filtering. Now in 6.0 things changed. Whole url handling is done internally (classes from private folder) and I don't want to change them since it will break on the next update.
So where is now the place in my project code to tell cordova to allow or not a specific request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in the cordova code and some debugging I found a way to keep the cordova code untouched and intercept the requests. When processing a request Cordova checks all plugins that respond to

```
- (BOOL)shouldOverrideLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and depending on the return value allows or blocks the request. So I created a small plugin which has only that method and returns `YES` if the request should be processed as usual by cordova, or `NO` to block it and do own handling.

Comment: How do you add the plugin that you created to  plugin objects so that it responds and returns YES?

Comment: It's a usual cordova plugin, follow that guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html
make sure that is defined to be autloaded in conifg.xml
<param name="onload" value="true" />

Comment: Thanks @Gamadril. I implemented as you said and could override the delegate. But, it doesn't have the webview object in it. What did you do for that?

Comment: Since your plugin extends CDVPlugin, you should be able to get the UIWebview from self.webView

Answer (score 0):

You can use native cordova [whitelisting](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html#ios-whitelisting).

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can see it only permit or not some requests, but not allow own handling.

Comment: yeah. you can handle it from cordova, why not ?

Comment: But how? How can I intercept for example a click on a link to a http-address and do own handling in code?

Comment: @Gamadril - Were you able to override the webview delegate? How can it be done..?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Controller by extending CDVViewController and implement the interface UIWebViewDelegate. Cordova will call your delegate method and depends on return value it will proceed.

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to implement the UIWebViewDelegate, but after that the external site won't launch anymore. Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?